# android: Observe 2 variables

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

// ViewModelFolder.selectFolder is MutableLiveData<String>
ViewModelFolder.selectFolder.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { name ->
  name?.let {
    taskViewModel.getTasksByFolder(it, false)
      .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tasks ->
        tasks?.let { taskAdapter.setTasks(it) }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I wanna call `taskViewModel.getTasksByFolder` when `ViewModelFolder.selectFolder` or tasks change. However, inner observer is called multiple times.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i think MediatorLiveData may help to solve this.

in your view model write a function like this.

```
fun mergeResult(): MediatorLiveData<String> {
        val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<String>()
        var result = ""

        mediatorLiveData.addSource(selectFolder) {
            // your logic goes here.
            result = ...
        }

        mediatorLiveData.addSource(getTasksByFolder) {
            // your logic goes here.
            result = ...
        }

        mediatorLiveData.value = result

        return mediatorLiveData
    }
```

and in your fragment observe it.

```
viewmodel.mergeResult().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
 . . .
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise but it doesn't work. Also I wanna return LiveData<List<Task>>>.